# Get uitreenode expanded state

Tags: matlab, user-interface, treeview

I have built a UI in Matlab, displaying a tree. I used the new UI components and want to save and restore the state of the expanded/collapsed nodes. Unfortunately I could not find a way to determine the current state of a tree node. Here's a simple example:

```
t = uitree(uigridlayout(uifigure, [1 1]));
p = uitreenode(t, 'Text', 'Parent');
uitreenode(p, 'Text', 'Child');
```

How can I determine the expanded state of the parent node `p`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a cellarray containing the identifier of the nodes that have been expanded.

The cellarray will be:

- set in the `TreeNodeExpanded` callback that is called when the user expands a node
- reset in the `TreeNodeCollapsed` callback that is called when the user collapes a node

Then you can create two pushbutton:

- one to save the cellarray
- one to load it and restore the node configuration

The callback associated to the pushbutton that loads the cellarray with list of the expanded nodes:

- collapses (with the [collapse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.container.tree.collapse.html) function) all the node to reset the status of the tree
- loops through the cellarray and expands (with the [expand](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.container.tree.expand.html) function) the nodes whose identifier has been stored (and read) in the ".mat" file

The following is a possible implementation of the proposed procedure in an app.

The `startupFcn` callback:

- identifies the nodes present in the app
- creates a cellarray containing the identifiers of all the nodes of the tree
- sets the `NodeData` property of each node to an integer values that will be used as index to acces to the cellarray

The `SaveTreeLeafstatusButtonPushed` and `LoadTreeLeafstatusButtonPushed` callbacks simply save and load a ".mat" file whios name is hard written in the code; you can easily update then using the [uigetfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) and [uiputfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiputfile.html) functions.

The `TreeNodeExpanded` callback:

- gets the index of the expanded node from its `NodeData` property
- retrieves the identifier of the node
- sets the corresponding element of the cellarray  that contains the identifier of the expanded nodes

The `TreeNodeCollapsed`:

- gets the index of the collapsed node from its `NodeData` property
- reset the corresponding element of the cellarray  that contains the identifier of the expanded nodes

The comments in the code should describe the main step summarized above.

```
    classdef SAVE_EXPAND_TREE < matlab.apps.AppBase

   % Properties that correspond to app components
   properties (Access = public)
      save_expand_tree          matlab.ui.Figure
      Label                     matlab.ui.control.Label
      LoadTreeLeafstatusButton  matlab.ui.control.Button
      SaveTreeLeafstatusButton  matlab.ui.control.Button
      Tree                      matlab.ui.container.Tree
      Level0Node                matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_1_Node_1            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_2_Node_1            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_2_Node_2            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_3_Node_1            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_3_Node_2            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_1_Node_2            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_2_Node_3            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_2_Node_4            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_1_Node_3            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_2_Node_5            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
      Level_2_Node_6            matlab.ui.container.TreeNode
   end

   
   properties (Access = private)
      tree_leaf_status;    % Property in which to store the status of the tree leaves
      tree_leaf_obj_names; % Property in which tyo store the names of the tree objects
   end
   

   % Callbacks that handle component events
   methods (Access = private)

      % Code that executes after component creation
      function startupFcn(app)
         % Initialize the property in which to store the status of the tree leaves as an empty
         % cell array
         % Each element of the cellarray contains the name of a node of the tree
         % The NodeData property of each node contains an integer value. This is used as an index
         % to access the elements in the cellarray
         % Initilize the the cellarray containing the namens of the tree objects
         % Set the node idx in its NodeData property
         app_fields=fieldnames(app);
         cnt=0;
         for i=1:numel(app_fields)
            if(isa(app.(app_fields{i}),'matlab.ui.container.TreeNode'))
               cnt=cnt+1;
               app.(app_fields{i}).NodeData=cnt;
               app.tree_leaf_obj_names{app.(app_fields{i}).NodeData}=app_fields{i};
            end
         end
      end

      % Node expanded function: Tree
      function TreeNodeExpanded(app, event)
         node = event.Node;
         % Set the element of the tree_leaf_status cellarray corresponding to the index stored in
         % the NodeData property of the node that has been expanded to the name of the node itself

         % Get the idx of the expanded node
         idx=node.NodeData;
         % Set the element of the tree_leaf_status cellarray to the name of the node object
         app.tree_leaf_status{idx}=app.tree_leaf_obj_names{idx};
      end

      % Node collapsed function: Tree
      function TreeNodeCollapsed(app, event)
         node = event.Node;
         % Get the idx of the collapsed node
         idx=node.NodeData;
         % Reset the lement of the tree_leaf_status cellarray
         app.tree_leaf_status{idx}='';
      end

      % Button pushed function: SaveTreeLeafstatusButton
      function SaveTreeLeafstatusButtonPushed(app, event)
         % Get the tree_leaf_status cellarray
         tmp_tree_leaf_status=app.tree_leaf_status;
         % Save the tree_leaf_status cellarray in a ".mat" file
         save('tmp_tree_leaf_status.mat','tmp_tree_leaf_status')
      end

      % Button pushed function: LoadTreeLeafstatusButton
      function LoadTreeLeafstatusButtonPushed(app, event)
         % Check if the ".mat" file exists
         if(exist("tmp_tree_leaf_status.mat","file"))
            create_gif('tree_leaf.gif',app.save_expand_tree,1.5,0)
            app.Label.Text='Loading tmp_tree_leaf_status.mat';
            create_gif('tree_leaf.gif',app.save_expand_tree,1.5,1)
            % Load the tree_leaf_status ".mat" file
            load('tmp_tree_leaf_status.mat')
            % Collapse all the leaf of the tree
            collapse(app.Tree,'All')
            app.Label.Text='All Tree leaf collapsed before restoring the loaded status';
            create_gif('tree_leaf.gif',app.save_expand_tree,1.5,1)
            % loop through the leaf of the tree and expand those saved in the ".mat" file
            for i=1:numel(app.tree_leaf_status)
               tmp_tree_leaf_status{i};
               if(~isempty(tmp_tree_leaf_status{i}))
                  app.Label.Text=['Expanding ' tmp_tree_leaf_status{i}];
                  expand(app.(tmp_tree_leaf_status{i}))
                  create_gif('tree_leaf.gif',app.save_expand_tree,1.5,1)
               end
            end
         end
      end
   end

   % Component initialization
   methods (Access = private)

      % Create UIFigure and components
      function createComponents(app)

         % Create save_expand_tree and hide until all components are created
         app.save_expand_tree = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
         app.save_expand_tree.Position = [100 100 541 381];
         app.save_expand_tree.Name = 'Save & Restore Tree Leaft Status';

         % Create Tree
         app.Tree = uitree(app.save_expand_tree);
         app.Tree.NodeExpandedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @TreeNodeExpanded, true);
         app.Tree.NodeCollapsedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @TreeNodeCollapsed, true);
         app.Tree.Position = [22 105 279 277];

         % Create Level0Node
         app.Level0Node = uitreenode(app.Tree);
         app.Level0Node.Text = 'Level 0 Node';

         % Create Level_1_Node_1
         app.Level_1_Node_1 = uitreenode(app.Level0Node);
         app.Level_1_Node_1.Text = 'Level 1 Node 1';

         % Create Level_2_Node_1
         app.Level_2_Node_1 = uitreenode(app.Level_1_Node_1);
         app.Level_2_Node_1.Text = 'Level 2 Node 1';

         % Create Level_2_Node_2
         app.Level_2_Node_2 = uitreenode(app.Level_1_Node_1);
         app.Level_2_Node_2.Text = 'Level_2 Node 2';

         % Create Level_3_Node_1
         app.Level_3_Node_1 = uitreenode(app.Level_2_Node_2);
         app.Level_3_Node_1.Text = 'Level 3 Node 1';

         % Create Level_3_Node_2
         app.Level_3_Node_2 = uitreenode(app.Level_2_Node_2);
         app.Level_3_Node_2.Text = 'Level_3_Node_2';

         % Create Level_1_Node_2
         app.Level_1_Node_2 = uitreenode(app.Level0Node);
         app.Level_1_Node_2.Text = 'Level 1 Node 2';

         % Create Level_2_Node_3
         app.Level_2_Node_3 = uitreenode(app.Level_1_Node_2);
         app.Level_2_Node_3.Text = 'Level 2 Node 3';

         % Create Level_2_Node_4
         app.Level_2_Node_4 = uitreenode(app.Level_1_Node_2);
         app.Level_2_Node_4.Text = 'Level 2 Node 4';

         % Create Level_1_Node_3
         app.Level_1_Node_3 = uitreenode(app.Level0Node);
         app.Level_1_Node_3.Text = 'Level 1 Node 3';

         % Create Level_2_Node_5
         app.Level_2_Node_5 = uitreenode(app.Level_1_Node_3);
         app.Level_2_Node_5.Text = 'Level 2 Node 5';

         % Create Level_2_Node_6
         app.Level_2_Node_6 = uitreenode(app.Level_1_Node_3);
         app.Level_2_Node_6.Text = 'Level 2 Node 6';

         % Create SaveTreeLeafstatusButton
         app.SaveTreeLeafstatusButton = uibutton(app.save_expand_tree, 'push');
         app.SaveTreeLeafstatusButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @SaveTreeLeafstatusButtonPushed, true);
         app.SaveTreeLeafstatusButton.Position = [339 289 165 33];
         app.SaveTreeLeafstatusButton.Text = 'Save Tree Leaf status';

         % Create LoadTreeLeafstatusButton
         app.LoadTreeLeafstatusButton = uibutton(app.save_expand_tree, 'push');
         app.LoadTreeLeafstatusButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @LoadTreeLeafstatusButtonPushed, true);
         app.LoadTreeLeafstatusButton.Position = [339 219 165 33];
         app.LoadTreeLeafstatusButton.Text = 'Load Tree Leaf status';

         % Create Label
         app.Label = uilabel(app.save_expand_tree);
         app.Label.FontWeight = 'bold';
         app.Label.FontColor = [1 0 0];
         app.Label.Position = [22 30 482 59];
         app.Label.Text = '';

         % Show the figure after all components are created
         app.save_expand_tree.Visible = 'on';
      end
   end

   % App creation and deletion
   methods (Access = public)

      % Construct app
      function app = SAVE_EXPAND_TREE

         % Create UIFigure and components
         createComponents(app)

         % Register the app with App Designer
         registerApp(app, app.save_expand_tree)

         % Execute the startup function
         runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

         if nargout == 0
            clear app
         end
      end

      % Code that executes before app deletion
      function delete(app)

         % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
         delete(app.save_expand_tree)
      end
   end
end
```

[image]